# Trying to understand why this "while" loop doesn't work as expected in React/JSX/node?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, while-loop, jsx

Simple problem that I haven't found a solution to.  Trying to read a variable found inside a Firebase document "NumberOfQuestionsInList" starting with list 1 and going to the value of "Maximum". At first attempted a simple solution like below, however the while loop doesn't act in synchronous order and therefore the while loop continues increasing without ever calling the .get() function:

```
let booleanValue = false;

while(booleanValue===false){

    const QListDirectory = firestore.collection("content").doc(`List${i}`);

        QListDirectory.get().then((docSnapshot) => {

            if (docSnapshot.exists) {

                    QListDirectory.onSnapshot((doc) => {

                        let NumberInList= doc.data().NumberOfQuestionsInList;
                        

                        //Series of if, else if statements depending on the value of the "NumberInList".
                        //These if(), else if() statements contain commands to change "booleanValue" to true.
                        //when other conditions are met.


                     });
            }

   });

//Iterate over i, moving from List1, to List2 and so on....
i=i+1;

}
```

What I end up observing is just a while loop that continues to increase i by 1 and never appears to actually .get() and of the Firebase document information. Any clarity as to why a while loop like this isn't allowed would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're performing an async operation inside the loop. The loop will not wait for that to complete

Comment: Is there any way to cause the loop to wait until operations are completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is happening here is that you have the get of the promise that reads to the firestore taking some time and since you have more code to run (the `i=i+1;`) outside of the promise you are just skipping the portion of the `.then((docSnapshot)` completely. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) you can see the anatomy of a promise

What you should do is first add a catch for that promise which is a really important part of a promise, and then move that `i=i+1;` inside of your your promise and also include it in your catch section so in case of an exception the loop continues.

Another possible solution here is to change from promises to async and declare your function as an async function, then you can use something like this

```
async function myloop() {
    const QListDirectory = firestore.collection("content").doc(`List${i}`);
    
    const docSnapshot = await QListDirectory.get();
    return docSnapshot.get("NumberOfQuestionsInList");        
}
```

This may not be the exact code that you need since you have multiple things to do that are redacted but this gives you an idea of another possible solution

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Chris32.  Unfortunately I am trying to conduct this while loop inside a React action dispatch, which has various asynch/synch limitations.  I will need to find another way to get the functionality I am looking to achieve.